# Los datos de mi ListView no se refrescan hasta pulsar mi EditText

Tags: android, listview, activity, fragment, edittext

Espero me puedan ayudar, verán tengo un menú hamburguesa del cual carga en su actividad principal un FRAGMENT con un LISTVIEW y un EDIT TEXT(para buscar en la lista),Cuando inicio se llena normal y muestra la info okey, PERO cuando en el menú lateral de mi menu hamburguesa selecciono otro item para cambiar de fragmento el cual contiene igual un LISTVIEW y un EDITTEXT no muestra la info de la lista HASTA que presiono el EDITTEXT.

ESPERO ME PUEDAN AYUDAR.
PD: la lista la lleno consumiendo un servicio y utilizo un adapter para personalizar mis elementos.

**Clase MainActivity:**

```
package jonathanc.ygo_card_finder;

import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import jonathanc.ygo_card_finder.card_list.cardListFragment;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    /*FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)  findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action",   Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
*/
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    cardListFragment nuevoFragmento = new cardListFragment();
   // expansionListFragment nuevoFragmento= new expansionListFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, nuevoFragmento);
    transaction.commit();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
 }

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
        expansionListFragment nuevoFragmento= new expansionListFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.main_container, nuevoFragmento);
        transaction.commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
 }
}
```

**Clase expansionListFragment:**

```
package jonathanc.ygo_card_finder;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import jonathanc.ygo_card_finder.card_info.ContainerActivity;
import jonathanc.ygo_card_finder.card_list.carta;
import jonathanc.ygo_card_finder.card_list.cartaAdapter;

/**
  * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
  */
 public class expansionListFragment extends Fragment implements   AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

ArrayList<cardSet> setsArrayList = new ArrayList();
ListView listView;
EditText editText;
Activity activity = getActivity();
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
cardSetAdapter setsAdapter;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_expansion_list, container, false);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle state) {
    super.onActivityCreated(state);
    pinta();
}

private void pinta() {
    listView = getView().findViewById(R.id.lista);
//        sv=findViewById(R.id.searchView1);

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    String url = "http://yugiohprices.com/api/card_sets";
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Cargando la lista de sets existentes");
    progressDialog.show();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        String url_image;
                        String nombreCarta;
                        String respuestaCodificada = new String(response.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"), "UTF-8");
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(respuestaCodificada);
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            nombreCarta = jsonArray.get(i).toString();
                            url_image = "http://yugiohprices.com/api/set_image/" + jsonArray.get(i).toString();
                            //Log.v("HOLI", url_image);
                              setsArrayList.add(new cardSet(nombreCarta, url_image));

                        }
                        progressDialog.cancel();


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener()

    {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Woops hubo un problema inesperado!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressDialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    queue.add(stringRequest);

    setsAdapter = new cardSetAdapter(getActivity(), setsArrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(setsAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

    editText = getView().findViewById(R.id.search);

    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setsAdapter.getFilter().filter(arg0);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    TextView textView = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_name2);//TODO
    /*Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), ContainerActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("nombreCarta", textView.getText().toString());
    startActivity(intent);
*/

    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "POSICION : " +  textView.getText().toString(),
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

}
```

**Clase cardSetAdapter :**

```
package jonathanc.ygo_card_finder;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class cardSetAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

public cardSetAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<cardSet> setsArray) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.setsArray = setsArray;
    this.listFiltered = setsArray;

}
cardSetAdapter.CustomFilter filter;
protected Activity activity;
protected ArrayList<cardSet> setsArray;
ArrayList<cardSet> listFiltered;



@Override
public int getCount() {
    return setsArray.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return setsArray.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return setsArray.indexOf(getItem(position));    }

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inf = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.sets, null);
    }
    cardSet dir = setsArray.get(position);

    ImageView imageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    Picasso.get().load(dir.getImagen()).into(imageView);

    TextView textView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_name2);
    textView.setText(dir.getNombre());

    return convertView;
}
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(filter == null)
    {
        filter=new cardSetAdapter.CustomFilter();
    }

    return filter;
}

//INNER CLASS
class CustomFilter extends Filter
{

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        FilterResults results=new FilterResults();

        if(constraint != null && constraint.length()>0)
        {
            //CONSTARINT TO UPPER
            constraint=constraint.toString().toUpperCase();

            ArrayList<cardSet> filters=new ArrayList<cardSet>();

            //get specific items
            for(int i=0;i<listFiltered.size();i++)
            {
                if(listFiltered.get(i).getNombre().toUpperCase().contains(constraint))
                {
                    cardSet p=new cardSet(listFiltered.get(i).getNombre(), listFiltered.get(i).getImagen());

                    filters.add(p);
                }
            }

            results.count=filters.size();
            results.values=filters;

        }else
        {
            results.count=listFiltered.size();
            results.values=listFiltered;

        }

        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        setsArray=(ArrayList<cardSet>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba esto, en la clase Clase ExpansionListFragment:

```
//despues de esto:
setsAdapter = new CardSetAdapter(getActivity(), setsArrayList);
listView.setAdapter(setsAdapter);
//notificas
setsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Aun asi deberias de tener una clase que extienda de FragmentPagerAdapter, que sea la encargada de los cambios entre fragmentos, deberias de utilizar un ViewPager que contenga el ListView, la clase deberia de ser asi:

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public CategoryAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return new ExpansionListFragment();
            case 1:
                return new ExpansionListFragment();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Para cambiar de fragmento usa esto:

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
o este otro viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
```

Para utilizarla debes de hacerlo asi, en tu `MainActivity`:

```
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    adapter = new CategoryAdapter(fragmentManager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

He incluso agregarle un `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` para poder pasar de un fragmento a otro deslizando lateralmente, o por ejemplo cambiar el titulo de arriba para distinguirlos:

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
```

Este podria ser el ViewPager:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbarSize="150dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Este podria ser el item layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:divider="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Y solo te faltaria el item, que podria ser asi:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- Layout for a single list item -->
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="3dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: intenta notifyAll

Comment: LISTO, EN EFECTO ERA EL setsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); PERO NO DESPUES DE listView.setAdapter(setsAdapter); SI NO DENTRO DE MI LLAMADA A LA API DESPUES DEL CICLO FOR